# Trever Noah's "Born a crime"

Tags: grammar

Is the title "Born a crime" grammatically correct? I thought it should have been "Born a criminal" or "Born into a crime".

Comment: How are you going to use it?

Comment: Have you read the book?  His birth was technically a crime.

Comment: I'm not using it, just curious since I saw the title of the book read "Born a crime".

Comment: Trevor Noah's parents are of mixed race, and because they were living in S.Africa under apartheid his parents, a white father, and a black mother, committed a "crime" when he was conceived. That's what I understand from watching a few interviews.

Comment: 'A Crime was Born' would be a more potent title.

Answer (score 0):

'Born a crime' is a great title, in the context of what others explain about the content of the book. As the author shouhld or could not legally exist - it means that his birth is 'a crime' - his existence 'is a crime' - which the title explains perfectly.